# Intl.NumberFormat works differently in safari than in chrome

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, cross-browser

I am working on a vue project in which global filters are being used. I have defined a global filter to format the number to Japanese currency format. It is working fine in chrome. But in safari it has different output.
In chrome i get the correct formatting (e.g 1938500)

```
¥1,938,500
```

but in safari of version 15.3 i get

```
JP¥1,938,500
```

code snippet for the filter is given below

```
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("jp-JP", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "JPY",
    minimumFractionDigits: 0
  });
  return formatter.format(value);
```

Any help would be grateful

Thank you

Comment: Firefox gives me `JP¥` as well, even though MDN says it should return just `￥`. I don't think `JP¥` is wrong per se, since the symbol is [also the currency symbol for the chinese yuan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen_and_yuan_sign)

Comment: Generally I wouldn't rely on this information to be 100% in sync across browsers, It's likely down to the implementation and source of data the browser vendor uses

Comment: humm...
it is a valid point that different browsers have different implementations

Comment: May be i need to use some library to make the formatting consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Country code for Japan is `JP`. 
 Language code for Japanese is `ja`.

Try this:

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("ja-JP", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "JPY",
  minimumFractionDigits: 0
});
```